# consolibyte quickbooks php to add simple xml

Tags: php, web, quickbooks, connector

I'm using the awesome consolibyte framework for Quickbooks but I'm having trouble adding a simple xml request. I have the web connector set up and it successfully runs through the update with no error, but nothing gets added to quickbooks. I'm testing with Keith's sample xml and I also tried my own xml that I know successfully inserts time through the Quickbooks SDK.
I'm using the sample file docs/web_connector/example_web_connector.php I've also  tried other sample files but nothing ever added to Quickbooks. I'm developing locally so not using https. 
Log files don't show errors. Any suggestions? Thanks.

sample-time.php is the file that i'm connecting to: (I edited the example_web_connector.php file). I removed most of the comments.

Shouldn't it queue up the xml and add ConsoliBYTE, LLCxxxx to the customer list?

```
    <?php
// I always program in E_STRICT error mode... 
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// We need to make sure the correct timezone is set, or some PHP installations will complain
if (function_exists('date_default_timezone_set'))
{
    // * MAKE SURE YOU SET THIS TO THE CORRECT TIMEZONE! *
    // List of valid timezones is here: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php
    date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
}

// Require the framework
require_once '../QuickBooks.php';

$user = 'quickbooks';
$pass = 'password';   

// Map QuickBooks actions to handler functions
$map = array(
    QUICKBOOKS_ADD_CUSTOMER => array( '_quickbooks_customer_add_request', '_quickbooks_customer_add_response' ),    
    );

// This is entirely optional, use it to trigger actions when an error is returned by QuickBooks
$errmap = array(
    3070 => '_quickbooks_error_stringtoolong',         
    );

// An array of callback hooks
$hooks = array(     
    );

// Logging level

$log_level = QUICKBOOKS_LOG_DEBUG;              

$soapserver = QUICKBOOKS_SOAPSERVER_BUILTIN;        // A pure-PHP SOAP server (no PHP ext/soap extension required, also makes debugging easier)

$soap_options = array(      // See http://www.php.net/soap
    );

$handler_options = array(

    'deny_concurrent_logins' => false, 
    'deny_reallyfast_logins' => false, 
    );      // See the comments in the QuickBooks/Server/Handlers.php file

$driver_options = array(        
    );

$callback_options = array(
    );    

$dsn = 'mysql://douggie:testit@localhost/test';    

if (!QuickBooks_Utilities::initialized($dsn))
{
    // Initialize creates the neccessary database schema for queueing up requests and logging
    QuickBooks_Utilities::initialize($dsn);

    // This creates a username and password which is used by the Web Connector to authenticate
    QuickBooks_Utilities::createUser($dsn, $user, $pass);       

    $primary_key_of_your_customer = 10023;

    $Queue = new QuickBooks_WebConnector_Queue($dsn);
    $Queue->enqueue(QUICKBOOKS_ADD_CUSTOMER, $primary_key_of_your_customer);    
}

// Create a new server and tell it to handle the requests
// __construct($dsn_or_conn, $map, $errmap = array(), $hooks = array(), $log_level = QUICKBOOKS_LOG_NORMAL, $soap = QUICKBOOKS_SOAPSERVER_PHP, $wsdl = QUICKBOOKS_WSDL, $soap_options = array(), $handler_options = array(), $driver_options = array(), $callback_options = array()
$Server = new QuickBooks_WebConnector_Server($dsn, $map, $errmap, $hooks, $log_level, $soapserver, QUICKBOOKS_WSDL, $soap_options, $handler_options, $driver_options, $callback_options);
$response = $Server->handle(true, true);    

function _quickbooks_customer_add_request($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $version, $locale)
{       
    // But we're just testing, so we'll just use a static test request:

    $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <?qbxml version="2.0"?>
        <QBXML>
            <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
                <CustomerAddRq requestID="' . $requestID . '">
                    <CustomerAdd>
                        <Name>ConsoliBYTE, LLC (' . mt_rand() . ')</Name>
                        <CompanyName>ConsoliBYTE, LLC</CompanyName>
                        <FirstName>Keith</FirstName>
                        <LastName>Palmer</LastName>
                        <BillAddress>
                            <Addr1>ConsoliBYTE, LLC</Addr1>
                            <Addr2>134 Stonemill Road</Addr2>
                            <City>Mansfield</City>
                            <State>CT</State>
                            <PostalCode>06268</PostalCode>
                            <Country>United States</Country>
                        </BillAddress>
                        <Phone>860-634-1602</Phone>
                        <AltPhone>860-429-0021</AltPhone>
                        <Fax>860-429-5183</Fax>
                        <Email>Keith@ConsoliBYTE.com</Email>
                        <Contact>Keith Palmer</Contact>
                    </CustomerAdd>
                </CustomerAddRq>
            </QBXMLMsgsRq>
        </QBXML>';

    return $xml;
}    

function _quickbooks_customer_add_response($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $xml, $idents)
{           
}    

function _quickbooks_salesreceipt_add_request($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $version, $locale)
{
    /*
        <CustomerRef>
            <ListID>80003579-1231522938</ListID>
        </CustomerRef>  
    */

    $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <?qbxml version="2.0"?>
        <QBXML>
            <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
                <SalesReceiptAddRq requestID="' . $requestID . '">
                    <SalesReceiptAdd>
                        <CustomerRef>
                            <FullName>Keith Palmer Jr.</FullName>
                        </CustomerRef>
                        <TxnDate>2009-01-09</TxnDate>
                        <RefNumber>16466</RefNumber>
                        <BillAddress>
                            <Addr1>Keith Palmer Jr.</Addr1>
                            <Addr3>134 Stonemill Road</Addr3>
                            <City>Storrs-Mansfield</City>
                            <State>CT</State>
                            <PostalCode>06268</PostalCode>
                            <Country>United States</Country>
                        </BillAddres>
                        <SalesReceiptLineAdd>
                            <ItemRef>
                                <FullName>Gift Certificate</FullName>
                            </ItemRef>
                            <Desc>$25.00 gift certificate</Desc>
                            <Quantity>1</Quantity>
                            <Rate>25.00</Rate>
                            <SalesTaxCodeRef>
                                <FullName>NON</FullName>
                            </SalesTaxCodeRef>
                        </SalesReceiptLineAdd>
                        <SalesReceiptLineAdd>
                            <ItemRef>
                                <FullName>Book</FullName>
                            </ItemRef>
                            <Desc>The Hitchhiker\'s Guide to the Galaxy</Desc>
                            <Amount>19.95</Amount>
                            <SalesTaxCodeRef>
                                <FullName>TAX</FullName>
                            </SalesTaxCodeRef>
                        </SalesReceiptLineAdd>
                    </SalesReceiptAdd>
                </SalesReceiptAddRq>
            </QBXMLMsgsRq>
        </QBXML>';

    return $xml;
}    

function _quickbooks_salesreceipt_add_response($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $xml, $idents)
{           
}    

function _quickbooks_error_stringtoolong($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $xml, $errnum, $errmsg)
{
    mail('your-email@your-domain.com', 
        'QuickBooks error occured!', 
        'QuickBooks thinks that ' . $action . ': ' . $ID . ' has a value which will not fit in a QuickBooks field...');
}
```

QWClog:

```
55 UTC  : QBWebConnector.WebServiceManager.DoUpdateSelected() : updateWS() for application = 'Time Keeper' has STARTED
20160830.21:31:55 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.getUpdateLock() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\UpdateLock = FALSE
20160830.21:31:55 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\UpdateLock has been set to True
20160830.21:31:55 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : ********************* Update session locked *********************
20160830.21:31:55 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : Initiated connection to the following application.
20160830.21:31:55 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : AppName: Time Keeper
20160830.21:31:55 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : AppUniqueName (if available): Time Keeper
20160830.21:31:55 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : AppURL: http://localhost/quickbooks-2016/docs/sample-time.php
20160830.21:31:55 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_serverVersion() : *** Calling serverVersion().
20160830.21:31:57 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_serverVersion() : Received from serverVersion() following parameter:<serverVersionRet="PHP QuickBooks SOAP Server v3.0 at /quickbooks-2016/docs/sample-time.php">
20160830.21:31:57 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_clientVersion() : *** Calling clientVersion() with following parameter:<productVersion="2.1.0.30">
20160830.21:32:00 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_clientVersion() : Received from clientVersion() following parameter:<clientVersionRet="">
20160830.21:32:00 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_clientVersion() : This application agrees with the current version of QBWebConnector. Allowing update operation.
20160830.21:32:00 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_authenticate() : Authenticating to application 'Time Keeper', username = 'quickbooks'
20160830.21:32:00 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_authenticate() : *** Calling authenticate() with following parameters:<userName="quickbooks"><password=<MaskedForSecurity>
20160830.21:32:02 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.updateWS() : Received from authenticate() following parameters:<authRet[0]="476baa7e-ee32-5e34-f90b-e3da55df0de5"><authRet[1]="none"><authRet[2]=""><authRet[3]="">
20160830.21:32:02 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setCurrentWebServiceName() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\CurrentWebServiceName has been set to Time Keeper
20160830.21:32:02 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setCurrentWebServiceSessionTicket() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\CurrentWebServiceSessionTicket has been set to 476baa7e-ee32-5e34-f90b-e3da55df0de5
20160830.21:32:02 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.CheckCFNResponse() : No data to exchange for this application. Job ending.
20160830.21:32:02 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_authenticate() : Done.
20160830.21:32:02 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\UpdateLock has been set to False
20160830.21:32:02 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : ********************* Update session unlocked *********************
20160830.21:32:02 UTC   : QBWebConnector.WebServiceManager.DoUpdateSelected() : No data to exchange for the application:  Time Keeper
```

Comment: You didn't post any logs, or any code, or give us any idea at all of what you've already tried, so unfortunately we can't help you. Please post your code, at the minimum, so that we can have at least a vague understanding of what you're doing.

Comment: Thanks Keith, I'll post more sample code when I get on the computer that I'm using to develop. I'm using the docs/web_connector/example_web_connector.php file and trying to add the sample xml from that file as a test. I'll post more later on.

Comment: Yes, please post your code. There is rarely, if ever, any way for anyone to help you unless you post your code. Please also tell us where you are in following the quick-start guide.

Comment: Where is the rest of your code? Specifically the code that you're using to queue stuff up? How far through the quick-start guide did you get?

Comment: I got it working with the docs\web_connector\example_app_web_connector files. One problem was that I was using the SQL files from an older version. I dropped all of those tables and let the code re-create them. Also I couldn't get my head around the idea that it's a two step process. 1. You create the xml request and queue it up in the database, then 2. the web connector requests that page where the xml is generated and added to Quickbooks. Correct me if I'm wrong,of course! Thanks.